# update the Map value for the key dynamically

Tags: java

I have a Map which holds the registrationID as key and the entire filePath for the information stored for that registered ID as the value.
I want to change the value dynamically for that path based on some conditional check.

```
void getDetails(final Map<String, String> detailsMap){

String filePath =  new File(details.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue()).getParent();
// key: 101A90Q  value : C:\Users\xyy\registeredDetails\101A90QInfo\101A90QInfo.xlsx
//sometimes the value of the detailsMap is dynamically changed (only the path, filename remains same) 

//logic to get the dynamic path
if(someCondCheck)
    filePath =  "c:\users\xyy\registeredDetails\conference"; //new path, but the filename i need to take from the old filePath value mentioned above. (101A90QInfo.xlsx)
}
//i want to update the map (detailsMap) with the above mentioned filePath along with the filename

   showRegisteredCompleteInfo(detailsMap);
}
```

I want to update the detailsMap which has the value as `C:\Users\xyy\registeredDetails\101A90QInfo\101A90QInfo.xlsx` with the updated filepath along with the filename
mentioned initially as `c:\users\xyy\registeredDetails\conference\101A90QInfo.xlsx`.
Can i updated the value of the Map without iterating again ? Please advice..

Comment: If you are able to use other libraries, you might want to take a look at Google Guava’s BiMap. It lets you get the inverse of the map, leading to O(1) lookups in both directions. https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html

Comment: First remove the final in methods parameter. And the just use detailsMap.put("registrationID", filePath) before the last line.

Comment: @Ganeshchaitanya - I cannot remove the final modifier in method parameter..

Comment: @ChrisGilardi - I should not use other libraries

Comment: @Ganeshchaitanya, `final` doesn't prevent modifying the content of the map, it just prevent you to change the instance itself like : `detailsMap = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: You are already reading the map, strangely I might add, with the iteration of the entry set. So just keep the `Entry` instance in memory to recover the key.

Comment: detailsMap.put("101A90Q", filePath); It will do the job for you as it will replace the previous value for same key with new one.

Answer (score 0):

## Entry.setValue

You are getting the first `Entry` in the set using

```
String filePath =  new File(details.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue()).getParent();
```

You can keep the `Entry` in memory to be able to get the `key` later.

```
Entry<String, String> e = details.entrySet().iterator().next();
String filePath = new File(e.getValue()).getParent();

...

e.setValue(filePath);
```

As mention by the [Entry javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#setValue(V)) :

> Replaces the value corresponding to this entry with the specified value (optional operation). (Writes through to the map.) The behavior of this call is undefined if the mapping has already been removed from the map (by the iterator's remove operation).

## Map.put

Or simply using the key directly on the map:

```
details.put(e.getKey(), filePath);
```

## Note

You are getting the first item in the entrySet, which doesn't give you any certitude on which it is. If you want to iterate the set, you need to update your code to read it using a loop :

```
for(Entry<String, String> e : details.entrySet()){
     ...
}
```